# Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project1.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    char name1[50];
    char address[50];
    char gender[50];
    char college[50];
    char hscmonth[10];
    char school[50];
    char sscmonth[10];
    int dd, mm, yyyy, cell1, cell2, hscyear, sscyear, cnic1, cnic2, cnic3;

    printf("\n****************************RESUME****************************");
    printf("\n******************************CV******************************");
    printf("\n**************************************************************");
    printf("\n==============================================================");
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    scanf_s("%s",name);
    printf("\nEnter Fathers name: ");
    scanf_s("%s",name1);
    printf("\nEnter Address: ");
    scanf_s("%s",address);
    printf("\nEnter Gender: ");
    scanf_s("%s",gender);
    printf("\nEnter College: ");
    scanf_s("%s",college);
    printf("\nEnter HSC Month: ");
    scanf_s("%s",hscmonth);
    printf("\nEnter HSC Year: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&hscyear);
    printf("\nEnter School: ");
    scanf_s("%s",school);
    printf("\nEnter SSC Month: ");
    scanf_s("%s",sscmonth);
    printf("\nEnter SSC Year: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&sscyear);
    printf("\nDate of Birth :");
    scanf_s("%d%d%d",&dd,&mm,&yyyy);
    printf("\nCell Phone :");
    scanf_s("%d%d",&cell1,&cell2);
    printf("\nCNIC :");
    scanf_s("%d%d%d",&cnic1,&cnic2,&cnic3);

    _getch();
}
```

my program crashes after the first scanf_s, I tried everything every tutorial available on you tube etc , but the error did not got resolved, hope I'll get my problem solved soon, please do explain when you reply as it is sort of assignment for me.If possible please do attach the correct code as well, Thank you

Comment: Microsoft's `scanf_s` is **not** a direct replacement for `scanf`, and some of the calls are missing one argument, which the compiler should have **warned** you about. You are using `scanf_s` with `%s` specifier incorrectly. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."*

Comment: Anyway, don't use the crappy Microsoft `scanf_s`, just use `scanf`, and put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` on the very first line of your .c file.

Comment: With `scanf` you can add a width specifier: `scanf("%49s",name);`

Comment: thank you so much guys , it fixed my problem.